# How do I get Jenkins to skip failed branches till they change?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with the Multiple SCMs + Git plugin.  Jenkins is correctly doing a new build for each branch, but for some reason when it fails a build it just keeps trying to redo the build, even if the branch has not changed.  How can I fix it so that Jenkins will move on to the next branch and only try to rebuild if the current branch changes?

Comment: I don't experience this behavior. When a job fails to build, Jenkins leaves it alone until it detects a change in the underlying source code repository.

Comment: What's your branch specifier?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar behavior with my Jenkins jobs when I had the Delete Workspace plugin installed and the "Delete workspace after the build is complete" checkbox was checked in the job configuration. The git plugin apparently needs to have a workspace where it stores the information about the branches it has seen and tried to build. If the post-build action wipes the workspace, git plugin loses its state.